# Stata foreach regression loop error

Tags: loops, foreach, stata

I am currently creating a loop which will run a regression for different regions. The regression I am trying to run is:

```
reg x1 x2 x3 if Region==n
```

where n=1,2,3,4,5,6.

Running them separately by manually typing is fine but when trying to run the following loop I've written:

```
local Region "1 2 3 4 5 6"
foreach i of local 'Region' {
reg x1 x2 x3 if Region== 'i'
}
```

it reports the error:

```
 'i' invalid name
r(198);
```

Can anyone suggest some advice to remedy this error?

Comment: `foreach i of local 'Region'` should be `foreach i of local Region`. Also, you can omit " " while defining local.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem reported is not to do with `foreach` or `regress`, but with your use of local macros.

The left and right quotation marks around local macro references differ. Otherwise macro references could not be nested, which would be a severe problem. This is documented, e.g. [U] 18.3.1 in PDF documentation.

There are other problems with your code. Let's fix it first, using the correct quotation marks and fixing another syntax error:

```
local Region "1 2 3 4 5 6"
foreach i of local Region {
    reg x1 x2 x3 if Region == `i'
}
```

The assumption here is that you have a variable called `Region` and you are also defining a local macro with the same name. If that's true and some other assumptions are true, the above should work. Note how the macro name is **not** referenced in the call to `foreach`.

Note incidentally that this example can be simplified. Defining a local macro here is like putting objects into a bag only to take them out immediately afterwards. You don't need to do that.

```
foreach i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 {
    reg x1 x2 x3 if Region == `i'
}
```

Further, when the list is this simple, you can use `forvalues` instead:

```
forval i = 1/6 {
    reg x1 x2 x3 if Region == `i'
}
```

All that aside, check out `statsby` to see if it helps.

In summary:

1. Syntax error: Use different quotation marks in referring to local macros.
2. Syntax error: In looping with `foreach` over the elements of a local macro, name it, don't reference it.
3. Style error: Don't use local macros you don't need.
4. Style error: Use `forvalues` instead of `foreach` when it's equivalent.

Comment: Many thanks, the style and syntax errors are duly noted. May I ask, if I am using the 'forvalues' instruction and I want to carry out a seperate regression for each country, is there a way of telling Stata that I want to loop this regression across all "i" instead of specifying the values of "i"?

Comment: That's an FAQ: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/try-all-values-with-foreach/index.html Note that `search foreach` in Stata would have pointed to it.